# How to highlight most recent posts in a list

Tags: posts

I want to be able to highlight the most recent post in a list of recent posts. By highlight I mean bold or style slightly differently from the other posts. This is the code I use now:

```
<h2>Assignments</h2>
<ol>
<?php
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query('showposts=15&cat=188&order=ASC');
?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ol>
```

This simply returns a numbered list. I would like to style differently the most recent post (i.e. the last item on the list). How can this be done?

Comment: This link should help you out http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/build-a-featured-posts-section-for-wordpress/?search_index=18

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a better solution:

```
<h2>Assignments</h2>
<ol>
<?php
  $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
  $recentPosts->query('showposts=15&cat=188&order=DESC');
?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
<?php $ageunix = get_the_time('U');
$days_old_in_seconds = ((time() - $ageunix));
$days_old = (($days_old_in_seconds/86400));
?>
<?php if ($days_old > 3) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    </li>
<?php else : ?>
<li><strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using css ?

```
ol li:last-child {font-weight: 600}
```

Comment: Didn't know I could do that with CSS. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As of today you can use H[ighlight New Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/highlight-new-posts/) to highlight new posts for your visitors.

It works with a cookie that stores the most recent time of visit of your visitor. It then checks if a post was published after the last visit and if so, appends a "NEW" label to the post title.